# To show all conics passing through given points form a pencil, and giving explicit equations for these conics

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have to show that all conics passing through the points $a = (1:0:0),\ b = (0:1:0),$ $\ c = (0:0:1),\ d = (1:1:1)$ in $\mathbb{P}_2$ form a pencil, and write an explicit equation for the conics of this pencil. I'm struggling on how to start the computation at all. Any hints or suggestions on how to begin will be helpful

Comment: Firstly, each point corresponds to a hyperplane in the $\mathbb P^5$ of plane conics, so their intersection *should* be a line, proving that this family is a pencil. If you want to check this rigorously, you should be able to write down a matrix of some sort whose columns correspond to the hyperplanes, and check that it has the appropriate rank.

Comment: Secondly, the equation of a pencil parametrized by $(s:t) \in \mathbb P^1$ is $sF + tG = 0$, where $F,G$ are any two independent members of the pencil. Finding conics through the four points is easy if you recall that there must be singular curves in the pencil, so we can take line pairs like $\overline{ab}\cup\overline{cd}$, which has equation $z(x-y) = 0$ obtained by multiplying the equations of the two lines.